# Can I crop the edges off an image in CSS without knowing the width of the image?

Tags: css

Is it possible to trim a set number of pixels off all sides of an image using CSS, without knowing the size of the image in advance?

I have a bunch of images that have a built-in border -- so, the border is part of the image itself. I would like to get rid of this border without having to edit all of the images. I would like to crop 2px of every side of the image using CSS.

I've seen different options, but they all seem to require knowing the width of the image to put that in CSS. However, the images are all different sizes, so I can't, for instance, hard-set a width 4px smaller than the actual width, and then fiddle with `overflow`.

Comment: You can probably use negative `margin`s and `overflow:hidden` on its container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a `clip-path` and `calc`...

Here I use 4px but you can use any value...provided the border width is known.

**Note** You do *not* need to know the image size.

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  margin: 4px;
}

img {
  display: block;
}

.clipped {
  clip-path: polygon( 4px 4px, calc(100% - 4px) 4px, calc(100% - 4px) calc(100% - 4px), 4px calc(100% - 4px))
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/284/196" alt="">
</div>

<div>
  <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/284/196" class="clipped">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another idea using `mask`

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  margin: 4px;
}

img {
  display: block;
}

.clipped {
  --c:4px;
  -webkit-mask:linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) center/calc(100% - 2*var(--c)) calc(100% - 2*var(--c)) no-repeat;
          mask:linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) center/calc(100% - 2*var(--c)) calc(100% - 2*var(--c)) no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/284/196" class="clipped">
</div>

<div>
  <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/284/196" class="clipped" style="--c:15px">
</div>
```